# ImageView not showing image from bitmap created by PDFRenderer on Android API 29

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, pdfrenderer

I have a PDF that I want to show in an ImageView.  It's showing on API 24-28 but no image shows on API 29.  I think the issue may be the bitmap created by the PDFRenderer.

I put a breakpoint after the `.render` method and (in the debugger) clicked "View Bitmap" here:
[image: Click "View Bitmap]

On API 29, I sometimes get the image, and sometimes I get this error:

> Error while evaluating expression, Object has been collected

[image: Preview of bitmap]

On API 24-28, I do not get this error.  I always get the image.

Below is the sample code:

```
        File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "fileName.pdf");
        PdfRenderer renderer = new PdfRenderer(ParcelFileDescriptor.open(file, ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY));
        if (currentPage < 0) {
            currentPage = 0;
        } else if (currentPage > renderer.getPageCount()) {
            currentPage = renderer.getPageCount() - 1;
        }
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(800, 1000, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, 800, 1000);
        PdfRenderer.Page page = renderer.openPage(currentPage);
        page.render(bitmap, rect, null, PdfRenderer.Page.RENDER_MODE_FOR_DISPLAY);
        page.close();
        renderer.close();
        image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        image.invalidate();
```

**Does anyone know why the image is always showing on API 24-28 but not on API 29?**

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this on API 30 also. It looks garbage collection may be more aggressive now for bitmaps. I solved this by changing the scope of the problem bitmap from private to public and setting it to null when the relevant view is destroyed.

Comment: hey I have made my bitmaps public and changed it to null when the view is no longer in use but it didnt work.

Comment: From my battles with a bitmap intensive app, I found i had to implement a two level recovery system to handle unpredictable null bitmaps. An lru type cache in a retained fragment plus a uri lookup in case the cache also failed.